# How to solve the merge conflict after revert one of the branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert, git-merge-conflict

So I have branch A and B, I rolled back one commit on B, then created a merge request from A to B, then git is complaining about merge conflicts.

I know if I checkout both branches locally, then resolve the conflicts locally then push A to git again, and that should fix the conflicts, the problem is that both branch are protected, and I can't push commits directly from either A or B, is there a way that I can fix the merge conflict?

Thanks.

Comment: is there a special reason why you don't want to solve the conflict?

Comment: So, you would have to say, merge B into A, solve the conflict, wrap the merge, then push into a feature branch, create a PR into A, then when that is accepted and merged, you will be able to merge A into B?

Comment: I don't want to change the current state of A, is there other solution?

Comment: Conflicts are a subject of their own. There are plenty of guide on how to solve then, this is _mine_, particularly, no tracking, no monetizing: http://ezconflict.com/en/conflicts.html

Comment: You can do the exact same path I described switching the branches. Merge A into B, solve the conflict, wrap up the merge, then push into a feature branch, create a PR, merge into B, then create a PR to merge B into A (this is all like github flow.... git standalone git it's a little simpler but still the same ideas behind it)

Comment: Sort it, thanks you very much @eftshift0